# finding the end day of each week for last 5 week

Tags: java, date

I am having some trouble creating some code that should dynamically print the date for last day of the week of the last 5 week.

Example output;

```
current date is 3/27/2014
End date of week 1 = 3/21/2014
End date of week 2 = 3/14/2014
End date of week 3 = 3/7/2014
End date of week 4 = 2/28/2014
End date of week 5 = 2/21/2014.
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance..

---

Thanks a lot guys .. and so sorry for the confusion.. actually i want code something which i prepared for finding last 4 weeks end date starting from the current date ..

```
public class dateValid6 {

public static void main(String[] args) {


int curDay = 22;
int curMonth = 3;
int curYear = 2014;
System.out.println("Current date = " + curMonth+"/"+curDay+"/"+curYear);

// if current day of month is between 30 to 25
if (curDay == 27 || curDay == 26 || curDay == 25 || curDay == 24 || curDay == 23 || curDay == 22)
{
    int curDayw1 = curDay - 6;
    String compDatew1 = (curMonth+"/"+curDayw1+"/"+curYear);
    System.out.println("Compared Date for Week 1 = "+compDatew1);

    int curDayw2 = curDayw1 - 7;
    String compDatew2 = (curMonth+"/"+curDayw2+"/"+curYear);
    System.out.println("Compared Date for Week 2 = "+compDatew2);

    int curDayw3 = curDayw2 - 7;
    String compDatew3 = (curMonth+"/"+curDayw3+"/"+curYear);
    System.out.println("Compared Date for Week 3 = "+compDatew3);

    int curDayw4 = 0;

    if (curMonth == 3)
    {
            curDayw4 = curDayw3 - 7;

            if(curDayw4 == 0)
            {
                curDayw4 = 28;
            }

            else if(curDayw4 == -1)
            {
                curDayw4 = 27;
            }

            else if(curDayw4 == -2)
            {
                curDayw4 = 26;
            }
            else if(curDayw4 == -3)
            {
                curDayw4 = 25;
            }
            else if(curDayw4 == -4)
            {
                curDayw4 = 24;
            }
            else if(curDayw4 == -5)
            {
                curDayw4 = 23;
            }
    }

    if (curMonth == 5 || curMonth == 7 || curMonth == 10 || curMonth == 12)
    {
            curDayw4 = curDayw3 - 6;

            if(curDayw4 == 0)
            {
                curDayw4 = 30;
            }

            else if(curDayw4 == -1)
            {
                curDayw4 = 29;
            }

            else if(curDayw4 == -2)
            {
                curDayw4 = 28;
            }
            else if(curDayw4 == -3)
            {
                curDayw4 = 27;
            }
            else if(curDayw4 == -4)
            {
                curDayw4 = 26;
            }
            else if(curDayw4 == -5)
            {
                curDayw4 = 25;
            }
    }

    if (curMonth == 1 || curMonth == 2 || curMonth == 4 || curMonth == 6 || curMonth == 8 || curMonth == 9 || curMonth == 11)
    {
            curDayw4 = curDayw3 - 6;

            if(curDayw4 == 0)
            {
                curDayw4 = 31;
            }

            else if(curDayw4 == -1)
            {
                curDayw4 = 30;
            }

            else if(curDayw4 == -2)
            {
                curDayw4 = 29;
            }
            else if(curDayw4 == -3)
            {
                curDayw4 = 28;
            }
            else if(curDayw4 == -4)
            {
                curDayw4 = 27;
            }
            else if(curDayw4 == -5)
            {
                curDayw4 = 26;
            }
    }

    curMonth = curMonth - 1;
    String compDatew4 = (curMonth+"/"+curDayw4+"/"+curYear);
    System.out.println("Compared Date for Week 5 = "+compDatew4);

    }

}
}
```

I need to complete this but with least code lines and for any date of the month.. Thanks a lot ....

Comment: "Hi please help me with java code." - Hi.. What code are you talking about?

Comment: Yes Java can do that easily. Look at java.util.Calendar

Comment: So your week ends on Friday??? You might try JodaTime-type `LocalDate` for this task.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603768/java-calendar-get-last-5-days-of-week-without-weekend?rq=1

Comment: What code have you written so far?  Are you stuck on a particular method or do you not know where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

The below example creates a `new GregorianCalendar();`, which represents today. We then create a `SimpleDateFormat` in the format you requested. After that we manipulate `c` to set it to the end of the week (Sunday, in this case) and then remove one week at a time in the loop and print the results through our `sdf`.

```
public class Test {             

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        c.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, GregorianCalendar.SUNDAY);
        System.out.println("End date of this week = "+sdf.format(c.getTime()));
        for(int i = 1 ; i <=5 ; i++){
            c.set(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, c.get(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)-1);
            System.out.println("End date of "+i+" week ago = "+sdf.format(c.getTime()));
        }          
    }
}
```

Output:

```
End date of this week = 03/30/2014
End date of 1 week ago = 03/23/2014
End date of 2 week ago = 03/16/2014
End date of 3 week ago = 03/09/2014
End date of 4 week ago = 03/02/2014
End date of 5 week ago = 02/23/2014
```

This is a full working example, so you can copy this to a new Java file called `Test.java` and it will run. I hope this helps.